# Using Vue.js img element in Typescript Array

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, tsx

I'm using Vue 2 and Typescript and I've declared a type in my `types.ts` file:

```
export type SetupSliderType = {
  name: SetupSliderEnum;
  image: HTMLImageElement;
  title: keyof I18nMessages;
  component: Function;
}
```

This gives me no errors.

In my `RegisterSetup.tsx` file I've declared an Array of that type:

```
private slides: Array<SetupSliderType> = [
    {
      name: SetupSliderEnum.solutions,
      image: <img src={solutions_logo}/>,
      title: I18nMessages['account.register.side.subheading'],
      component: this.renderSlideSolutions
    },
]
```

The 'image' line in my Array block gives me this error:

> Type 'VNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLImageElement': align, alt, border, complete, and 309 more.ts(2740)
>
> types.ts(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'image' which is declared here on type 'SetupSliderType'

What is the right way to use the `<img>` element for this syntax or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In my edit, I changed *"...I've declared a type enum in my..."* to *"...I've declared a type enum in my..."* because the type you've shown **isn't** an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#handbook-content), it's just a type (more specifically, it's a type alias for an object type). You might want to rename the `steps.enum.ts` file (or move the type elsewhere).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah yes it actually wasn't in my `enum` file it was in my `types.ts` file and I got mixed up because I also made an `enum` file for it that's irrelevant to the question, so I just edited it, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use JSX/TSX to create an element, you're not creating a **DOM** element, you're creating an object that will be used by Vue.js (or React or similar) *later* to create or update a DOM element. As the error message is telling you, the type of object in your case is `VNode`, so you'd use `VNode` instead of `HTMLInputElement` in your type:

```
export type SetupSliderType = {
    name: SetupSliderEnum;
    image: VNode; // <================
    title: keyof I18nMessages;
    component: Function;
}
```

If you actually wanted to create an `HTMLInputElement`, you could do that via `document.createElement`, but it would be very unusual when using a library like Vue.js or React or similar.

Comment: I see! That makes sense and using `VNode` worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry one last thing -- is just using the `<img/>` element the way I did in the Array block in the question the right way to do it? It gives no errors after using `VNode` but when running the page it all goes blank instead of outputting all the layouts and structuring I'd done. Every other page runs fine except the `RegisterSetup.tsx` page after using `VNode` (when reversed and taking out the image completely, it runs fine again)

Comment: @noufalsalem - I'm afraid I don't use Vue.js. :-| Sorry not to be of more help!